# Hovered image in android

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

I wrote a onTouchListner() for a imageView as this :

```
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.but_kh);
        final ImageView hover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hov_but);                    
        image.setOnTouchListener(new  OnTouchListener() { 

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                image.setVisibility(0);
                hover.setVisibility(100);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

As you see I set the visibility of image 0 ,but I don't know how to make it 100 when the hovering of image will finish ,it means that I want to change the visibility oh those two images as this after hovering:

```
                image.setVisibility(100);
                hover.setVisibility(0);
```

thanks in advance,

Comment: When you touch on the image, it vanishes and other one appears.And when you finger up, it appears and other one vanishes. Isn't this your plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                     image.setVisibility(0);
                                     hover.setVisibility(100);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                     image.setVisibility(100);
                                     hover.setVisibility(0);
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```